# Deleting a NSManagedObject that is a part of the set of the parent NSManagedObject

Tags: ios, core-data

I have a parent NSManagedObject (Person) and each person can have alarms, which is also a NSManagedObject.  When I go to the detail view of my Person object to look at the alarms, I want to be able to delete the alarms.  What I currently do to show in my table:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *SimpleCellIdentifier = @"SimpleCellIdentifier";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:SimpleCellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:SimpleCellIdentifier];
    }

    NSDate *theDate = [[self sortedTimes] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = [self.dateFormatter stringFromDate:theDate];

    return cell;
}

- (NSMutableArray *)sortedTimes {
    NSMutableArray *tempArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[self.person.alarms allObjects]];     // Alarm NSManagedObject
    tempArray = [tempArray valueForKey:@"time"];                                                            // NSDate value
    return [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[tempArray sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)]];
}
```

So I thought I could delete the last object by just doing:

```
[[self sortedTimes] removeLastObject];
[self saveContext];
```

But I believe that I get pointed to not the actual Alarm object since my sortedTimes might not point to the actual Alarms set.  I was wondering what I should do in this situation?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're just getting confused by what `removeLastObject` does. It is removing the object from your array that is being returned from `sortedItems`, it is not doing anything to the Alarm object, your context, or persistent store. I am not in love with the design here but given what you have you should be able to do the following.

```
Alarm *alarmToDelete = [[self sortedTimes] lastObject];
[myManagedObjectContext deleteObject:alarmToDelete];
[myManagedObjectContext save:&error];
```

This will delete the Alarm NSManagedObject from your context and the save the context (which will persist it to your persistent store). You will then need to reload your table so that it reflects the changes.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Do you have a better solution for the persistent store.  I'm always looking for better solutions.  The gist is basically a person has an alarm and can have multiple alarms.  So the persistent store is pretty simple.  It's just a one-to-many relationship from person to alarms.

Comment: Rather than having the `sortedItems` method that always returns a new array after sorting it I would set a sort descriptor on my `NSFetchRequest` that populates `self.people.alarms`. I wasn't referring to the design of the object graph, but the code itself. Hope the answer helped you delete the record though?

Comment: Yup, thanks.  Will try what you recommended as well.  Thanks!

Comment: I had a question regarding the NSFetchRequest to populate self.people.alarms, can you show an example of that?  I thought that self.people.alarms was an NSSet and using a fetchRequest returns an array.  So for my tableView delegate and datasource methods where I typically use an NSArray to populate the table, shouldn't I still use the array [self sortedItems] to populate those fields?  Please let me know if I'm wrong as I'm just learning this stuff.  Thanks!

Comment: I suppose it is probably not a big deal to have the `sortedTimes` method. Your other option would be to use a Fetched Property (https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdRelationships.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001857-SW7) or create a new fetch request on the alarm entity itself for the person and set sort descriptor on it. If it's work well then I wouldn't worry too much about it though. There are likely other things that are more important to focus on. Just some thoughts if you run into any performance issues.